# How to make a nested while loops in python?

Tags: python

It is obvious that the following code returns something like:

```
for i in range(5):
  print "i = ", i
  for j in range(5):
     print "j = ", j
```

returns:

```
i =  0
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
i =  1
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
i =  2
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
i =  3
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
i =  4
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
```

I would like to do the same with `while` loop. I have tried the following, but did not work:

```
i=0
j=0
while i<=5:
    print "i = ", i
    while j<=5:
        print "j = ", j
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

It gave:

```
i =  0
j =  0
j =  1
j =  2
j =  3
j =  4
j =  5
i =  1
i =  2
i =  3
i =  4
i =  5
```

I aim to have the same output.

Comment: Change the `6th` line `print "j = ", i` to `print "j = ", j`. It is a typo, i presume ? Reset `j = 0` before inner while loop starts

Comment: Even the most cursory trace with a debugger will highlight the problem, which gets you pretty close to how to fix it.

Comment: Do you think you should reset `j` to 0 somewhere in the loop?

Comment: @hansolo sorry, it was just a mistake. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same result with while loop, you must assign j=0 inside the loop, because in your first succeeded try you just print j, but with while loop you add `j = j + 1`. As a result `while j<=5:` will never be true again. Also use <5 or <=4
So:

```
i=0
while i<=4:
    print "i = ", i
    j=0
    while j<=4:
        print "j = ", j
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "j = ", i
```

You just accidentally printed the value of `i` here, but you expect the value of `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the Value of `j`.
Once the inner `while` executes for first time value of `j` becomes `5` and it will never satisfy the inner loop condition, so clear the value of `j` before inner loop.

```
i=0
j=0
while i<=4:
    print "i = ", i
    j = 0
    while j<=4:
        print "j = ", j
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0
j=0
while i<=5:
    print "i = ", i
    while j<=5:
        print "j = ", j
        j = j + 1
    # copy the second line here to re-initialize j
    j=0 
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi just tested this code, the output is the same !

```
i = 0
while i<5:
  print("i = ", i)
  i = i + 1
  j = 0
  while j<5:
     print ("j = ", j)
     j = j + 1
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the OP's problem? Code without an explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid firstly thank you for pointing my syntax error. Then no need of explanation for this problem. it was obvious that you have to reset the j value ...